# Generating view of cache object in Markdown document in R

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I cannot show object in markdown document that are objects generated in different R script(within the same session). I would like to point out that I am newbie to markdown. So the code is as follows(''' are added before and after):

`{r eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
head(output_by_size,10) # 1st line
summary(cars)           # 2nd line
dim(iris)               # 3rd line`

when I comment line 2nd and 3rd the following error is generated:
Error in head(output_by_size, 10) : object 'output_by_size' not found
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> head

When 1st line is commented, lines 2nd and 3rd work as expected. Output_by_size is just simple data frame object. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to load the data "output_by_size" to your .RMD file:

1. Don't knit your file with the Rstudio "knit" button, save your RMD file and then use the console:

   ```
   library(knitr) 
   knit('your_file.Rmd')
   ```

   This will take your recent environment into account and the error should be gone.
2. Store your "output_by_size" as "output_by_size.RData" and load it manually in your RMD file

   ````
   ```{r load myData, include=FALSE}
   load("output_by_size.RData")
   ```
   ````

   If you do it this way you can use the "knit" button from RStudio.

I hope one of this ways is a good solution for you.