# not found Calls: <Anonymous> error when knitting from r studio to HTML

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

```
{r,eval=F}
corfit <- duplicateCorrelation(brain.rma, design.trt, block = blocks)

{r histOfcorrelations}
print(cor)
{r}
plot(hist(tanh(corfit$atanh.correlations)))
```

My codes run just fine in the RMD file, but will not knit to HTML.

> Error in hist(tanh(corfit$atanh.correlations)) : object 'corfit' not
>   found Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible ->
>   eval -> eval -> plot -> hist Execution halted

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Error in hist(tanh(corfit$atanh.correlations)) : 
  object 'corfit' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> plot -> hist
Execution halted

Comment: I'm sure it will work, when you do not knit it with the knit-button in RStudio. Use the Console and `rmarkdown::render("<path-to-your-RMD-file">)`. I think you have objects in your environment, but when you knit it with RStudio-button, they will not took in account. Another solution is presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132675/generating-view-of-cache-object-in-markdown-document-in-r/40137250#40137250)

Comment: @J_F that worked. Thanks!

Comment: didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be because your statement eval=F.
This in fact makes knitr not to evaluate corfit and then the object can't be found.
Try to delete eval=F and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your code: "eval=F"

eval = FALSE prevents code from being evaluated. (And obviously if the code is not run, no results will be generated). This is useful for displaying example code, or for disabling a large block of code without commenting each line.
https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-evaluation